# How do I compare parallel string lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm a computer science major at UT and I'm taking a Python class this semester. The professor gave us a lab assignment I've been trying to figure out for the last 3 hours and gotten nowhere. So here I am asking for any help that you can offer. Here is the question:

> This program compares two parallel lists to grade a multiple choice
> exam. One list has the exam solution and the second list has a
> student's answers. The question number of each missed question is
> stored in a third list.
>
> You must use the three lists provided in your solution.
>
> Your solution must use indexing.
>
> Do not write any other user-defined functions
>
> Write all your code in the main function.
>
> You may not embed Python programming statements inside list brackets [ ]

I know I need to use a `for` loop in order to populate the third list, but I can't get down how to compare the two initial lists to have only the wrong answers populate the third list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Give it a shot and post your solution. People will be more helpful then.

Comment: _"Your solution must use indexing"_ - strange restriction for a Python program.

Comment: Ya... this whole program has me freaking honestly. the farthest I've been able to get so far is

   for item in exam_solution:
        if item not in student_answers:
            questions_missed.append(item)

Comment: @user3534918, Please update your question. You can't have multiline string in comments on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hello @user3534918 and welcome to Stack Overflow! I took the liberty of editing your question for grammar and clarity. Please feel free to change my edits or improve on it as you see fit. We also have a helpful [help] page.

Comment: Wow... thanks! Sorry about the poor quality of the post. I've been awake entirely too long trying to figure this issue out.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the solution, but I can give you a hint: consider doing a boolean comparison between each item. For example, if 'a' is the solution and 'b' is the student's answer, `a AND b` would yield 'true' if the two values are the same, i.e. the answer is correct.

On the other hand, the value would be 'false' if the answer is wrong. In this case... (you can finish the statement)

Comment: Boolean comparisons are If/else aren't they?

Comment: @Jay my answer was language-agnostic: it would be a good exercise to figure out how to do boolean logic in Python, and what 'is' and '==' actually do.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not very straightforward and the constraint to use indexing make it a simple for loop?

You have three lists, es (exam solutions), sa (student answers) and mq (missed questions). All you need to do is run a loop on index variable i ranging over length of es, compare es value with sa value to calculate score and append i to mq if the value in sa is '' or null or whatever signifies a missed question in sa.

Sorry if I missed or misunderstood something here.

Comment: Not at all, that's exactly what I need. For some reason I can't get it to work though. Can't figure out how to properly post the code I have so far as to display whatever I'm missing/doing wrong.

Comment: To post the code click on {} above the edit pane. Type the first line where indicated and just indent the rest of the code below. Also please dont forget to post the error / incorrect result showing up.